# Android keyboard keycodes

Tags: android, xml, keyboard-shortcuts

Hi i'm trying to make an android keyboard but i can't find the  key codes for any local Indian languages .
can anyone  tell me where can I find android keyboard keycodes.
I have tried searching Google for a couple of days now but I can't find anything

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for the codes
[UnicodeLink](https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%A4-brahmic-scripts/brahmic-scripts-1/)
You can use hexadecimal codes.

Comment: I'm looking for Kashmiri perso-arabic script i can't find it. There is only devangri script for Kashmiri

Comment: I think these characters covers all language characters just go throw these characters..you can find it.